# Proper angular syntax in haml

Tags: angularjs, haml

I am working on a Angular project with haml views and have the following code.

```
%textarea.answer{ |
    placeholder: 'Please enter your answer', |
    onfocus: '{ this.placeholder = " " }', |
    ng: { |
        model: 'canvasCtrl.stepToShow.answer', |
    } |                                                                                                                                     
} |
```

I wanted to add model-options like this:

```
%textarea.answer{ |
    placeholder: 'Please enter your answer', |
    onfocus: '{ this.placeholder = " " }', |
    ng: { |
        model: 'canvasCtrl.stepToShow.answer', |
        model-options: 'canvasCtrl.savingsOptions', |
    } |                                                                                                                                     
} |
```

I get though the following syntax error from haml:

syntax error, unexpected tLABEL ...pToShow.answer', model-options: 'canvasCtrl.savingsOptions',... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:53: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tSTRING_DEND ...s: 'canvasCtrl.savingsOptions', } )}>\n \n \n \n

\n On this page you wil... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected keyword_in, expecting tSTRING_DEND ... project. Start with filling in your project name and descri... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected keyword_then ...t name and description and then click on the first question.... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting '(' ...n click on the first question.\n

\n Hap... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected '<' ...e first question.\n

\n Happy Planning.... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: unknown regexp option - p projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected $undefined ...ppy Planning.\n

\n Your canvas Te... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...n Your canvas Team\n \n \n ... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: unknown regexp options - dv projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected $undefined ...Team\n \n \n \n\n", -4, f... ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: unknown regexp options - htl projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected $undefined ... \n \n\n", -4, false); ... ^ projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: unterminated string meets end of file projects/canvas/views/home.haml:65: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_DEND end;end;end;end ^

I also tried following but it didn't work:

```
 ng: { |
        model: {'canvasCtrl.stepToShow.answer', options: 'canvasCtrl.savingsOptions', } |
 } |
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `%input{ng_model_options: "{debounce: 250}"}`?  This works for me from a haml template